# Grub Rescue Stuck

Tags: grubrescue

Similar questions have been asked, but they didn't answer my problem.

I had a partition (Windows & Ubuntu). I deleted Ubuntu and now I am stuck in Grub-Rescue. I attempted to use 1) ls 2) set root 3) set prefix suggested in another question, but it didn't work for me.

I don't care about any of my files or software. I just want to be able to start from zero again. I have two ideas, I just need to know if they would work:

Idea 1: Somehow, delete everything in my hard disk. (How to do this in grub? )
Idea 2: Purchase a replacement hard disk (optiplex 990).

My assumption is that after doing #1 or #2, I would just be able to install Ubuntu from a USB, and this would be relatively easy. Is that correct or not?

I haven't done #1 because I don't know how to "wipe out" the hard disk from grub, if at all possible. I have a ubuntu.iso in my USB, but I don't know how to access it.

I haven't done #2 because I don't know if it will work.

Please tell me what should I do. Any help is really appreciated.

Edit: Could it help me to use a Ubuntu Live CD, instead of a USB? 
Clarification: I want to have Ubuntu, and I don't have a Windows CD anymore.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove Ubuntu and put Windows back on?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on)

Comment: Reading that post above, I am getting the impression that a Ubuntu Live CD might be an option? I don't want Windows. I want Ubuntu. I have Ubuntu on my USB, but it doesn't boot.

Comment: If you want Ubuntu, then why did you delete its partition?  Simply reinstall it if you want it.

Comment: I deleted it because I wanted to have only 1 partition (for more space). I don't know how to reinstall it now that I am stuck on grub-rescue.

Comment: The same way you installed it in the first place:  boot from cd or usb and go through the install proceedure.

Comment: I burned ubuntu.iso into my USB, but when I turn on the computer, it goes straight into grub-rescue. How do I make the computer go into installation?

Comment: I just burned a DVD with Ubuntu ISO, and tried to boot from the DVD. The screen starts out normal at first, it says F12 for boot options. I press F12 and nothing happens, and then I just end up in the same grub-rescue screen again.

Comment: You will have to figure out how to get your bios to boot from something other than the hard drive, just like you did the first time.

Comment: The first time somebody else helped me, so I don't really know how to fix this. Separate question: would this problem go away if I bought a new hard drive?

Comment: No; you just need to reinstall, and that always involves telling your bios to boot from removable media.  How to do that depends on your bios, but it usually tells you what key to press to do this when it is starting up.  Common keys are F12, Del, or F1.